# Binding custom listener to Backbone View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am new to javascript and Backbone.js. I would like to bind a custom listener to a Backbone view on initialization. For example, I would like to achieve something like this:

```
var CampaignListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
       this.on("customFunc")
    },
    customFunc: function() {
        if (this.$el.scrollTop() == 500 ) {
             console.log("this has occurred, time to do stuff")
          }
    }
)}
```

That whenever a user scrolls to a specified position, I can execute some code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is something you want to happen when the window scrolls, no? In that case you have a few options:

The first is something a bit more familiar, and close to what you have, using the `remove` method to cleanup that binding:

```
var CampaignListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
       // You probably want to add an identifier to the event name, like 'scroll.campainlist' or something
       $(window).on('scroll', _.bind(this.customFunc, this));
    },
    customFunc: function() {
        if (this.$el.scrollTop() == 500 ) {
             console.log("this has occurred, time to do stuff")
          }
    },
    remove: function() {
      $(window).off('scroll');
      Backbone.View.prototype.remove.call(this);
    }
)}
```

---

The other option is to use an [Event Aggregator](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/03/revisiting-the-backbone-event-aggregator-lessons-learned/) like so:

```
var vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);

$(window).on('scroll', function(ev) {
  vent.trigger('window:scroll', ev);
});

var CampaignListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
       this.listenTo(vent, 'window:scroll', this.customFunc);
    },
    customFunc: function() {
        if (this.$el.scrollTop() == 500 ) {
             console.log("this has occurred, time to do stuff")
          }
    }
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [delegateEvents](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) in Backbone Views. For example you could attach to the scroll event of your view, but of course it will fire with every scroll. I put together a quick and very simple jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/scottluskcis/5bqSU/1/) based on your example. Below is some of the JavaScript. Notice the use of the events{} in the code.

```
var CampainListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#list', 

    events: {
        'scroll': 'customFunc'    
    }, 

    initialize: function() { }, 

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(sampleHtml);
        return this; 
    }, 

    customFunc: function() {
        // console.log('scrolling... top is ' + this.$el.scrollTop()); 
        if (this.$el.scrollTop() >= 100 ) {
          console.log("this has occurred, time to do stuff")
        }
    }
}); 

var view = new CampainListView(); 
view.render();
```